# When using Team City snapshot dependencies, are you using the post build files of the snapshot or simply the SVN revision number?

Tags: asp.net, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have 2 build configurations in one project:

- Build & Test Code
- Deploy Code

I want Deploy Code to run only if Build & Test Code built successfully, so I set up a snapshot dependency.

Does a snapshot dependency mean that Deploy Code will check out the same SVN revision as Build & Test Code and then run the NAnt script against that checkout, which will not contain the compiler generated post-build files? Or, will a snapshot dependency on Build & Test Code from Deploy Code mean that the NAnt will run against the post-build, working directory files of Build & Test Code on the build agent?

**UPDATE:**

It seems if I put a snapshot dependency on Build & Test Code for Deploy Code and I have a build of the latest revision for Build & Test Code, my NAnt script will deploy the post-build files for that build of Build & Test Code.

I would still like to confirm that I understand the concept, as I don't really understand the Team City documentation. I think I should probably make sure Deploy Code runs on  the same build agent as Build & Test Code, otherwise I might run into a case where Deploy Code checks out the SVN revision and then just deploys the pre-build code files. Is this correct?

My confusion is mainly because it seems  you have to have a VCS setup for Deploy Code. Is that because it needs it to compare revision numbers to the snapshot dependency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Snapshot Dependency section of the Dependent Builds doco page](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Dependent+Build#DependentBuild-SnapshotDependency):

> A snapshot dependency from build configuration A to build
>   configuration B enforces that each build of A has a "suitable" build
>   of B so that both builds use the same sources snapshot (used sources
>   revisions correspond to the same moment).

So the idea of a snapshot dependency is that you can run a build against exactly the same *codebase* as another build which has successfully run against it.

If you want the "deploy code" build to run only after "build and test code" has successfully run, create a snapshot dependency in the second build and make sure it's set to "Only use successful builds from the suitable ones".

Keep in mind that this has nothing to do with artefacts; the second build will simply pull the same codebase and recompile it all over again. If you want to deploy the artefacts created from the first build, then you want to be looking at *artefact dependencies* instead. This is just what Paul has written about in his answer and is the correct approach.

Regarding your update, it sounds like those post-build files are only available because they're still on the build agent after the first build. Try running the first build then "cleaning sources" on the agent and running the second build. You'll find the original compilation output is no longer there and it will fail. This is important because if you have multiple build agents or go some time between the two builds you simply can't rely on the output that *isn't* saved as artefacts still being there.

And yes, the TeamCity documentation is confusing :)

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that, following your article series, I have a Build Trigger in the "deploy code" configuration on the "build and test code" configuration. Therefore, it's triggered by a successful build. It makes sense, in my case, that the post-build files are still there because we only have one build agent running, and "deploy code" should run very shortly, if not immediately, after "build and run test code". I think I'll switch to just saving artifacts anyway as that seems to be the better practice.

Comment: Is it suitable for packages? I have a lot of packages. Most of my projects use them. Can I create Build which only gather all packages and then use it as Snapshot Dependency for all other builds?

Answer (score 6):

I have a very similar setup in TeamCity except that I use MSBuild not NAnt but I use the same 2 step build process and if I explain how I've configured it then hopefully it will allow you to understand what you need to do.

So in my setup, Build 1 pulls the code from source control, compiles it and runs the unit tests. It then publishes all the files required for deployment as artifacts.

Build 2 has a snapshot **and** an artifact dependency on Build 1 and this means that it pulls no code, it just simply takes the artifacts from Build 1 and deploys them.

In practice this means I can trigger Build 2 and one of two things happen. If Build 1 is up to date then it simply deploys the artifacts from the last successful build of Build 1. However if Build 1 is not up to date then TeamCity will automatically trigger Build 1 and then run Build 2 straight afterwards using the artifacts from that build.

Comment: I've seen this sort of setup before, but I don't think the artifact dependency is necessary. I've got a proof of concept running now that runs a NAnt copy script with a dependency on the build/test configuration. It seems to be working fine so far, I'm just not sure if there's any case where it wouldn't include the .dlls generated by the build. 

I guess I'm just confused why a VCS configuration is needed on the build if it's not checking out anything, just using the post-build files from the dependency. I'm guessing it's just for comparing revision numbers.